# How to detect that android finished downloading in adb?

Tags: android, api, adb, android-download-manager

I have a script that does some things on an android phone.. one of the things is to download some files - which I need to wait for them to download before going to the next stage..

I tried to wait a static amount of time... didn't work because download time varies
I tried to search if the downloaded file exists with a loop, but the filename is not constant...

I'm looking for the way to detect if a download process from a certain process (or activity) is ongoing - via adb.. is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by checking the response from

```
adb shell dumpsys activity services | findstr download
```

when the response was 'nothing' that meant that the download service isn't running, else it returned the service record

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use:

```
adb shell service check com.android.providers.downloads
```

OR

```
adb shell ps com.android.providers.downloads
```

OR

```
adb shell dumpsys notifications | grep -i download
```

..and measure the length of the output to determine if the download service is running.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to listen on the "DownloadManager" tag, and silenced other tags:

> adb logcat DownloadManager:V *:S

For `zsh` users:

> adb logcat DownloadManager:V \*:S